# Generative Adversarial Networks (GAN) to generate time series data

Tags: time-series, gan

I see that there are cases of GANs used with Time Series. The paper [Recurrent (conditional) generative adversarial networks for generating real-valued time series data](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.02633) says that they generated synthetic data, just what I need.

- I am curious to know if I can create a time series of 1000 points from time series of 1000 points
- Is there a requirement for points in the time series (delta between nearest points) for the GAN to be effective?

Comment: Your question is too vague. There are no universal values for "how much data" and "what conditions". Do you have a specific application in mind? If so, please post more details about the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: As you suggested, I updated my comment

Comment: did you get any further in your research on GAN for time series ?